# How can I convert Posts into Custom type posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a Wordpress site that I just updated to 3.1. I want to make use of custom post types now, my question is how can I assign (transfer?) a post to a newly created custom post type ?

For example, all my articles (news, poems, ideas to change the world) are in Posts. Now I have created the custom post types News, Poems, etc. and I want to transfer my old posts to these new custom post types.

I hope this is clear enough, anybody ?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to consider whether you really wan to convert your posts to new post types. Read this article - it may help: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-and-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way is to [do it manually in the DB](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/convert-posts-to-custom-post-types). If you don't have access to the DB, or if you don't want to do it manually, you can install a [plugin that will do it one post at a time](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/), or a plugin that [will bulk convert a lot of posts at once](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/)

Answer (score 4):

there is  a great plugin [Post Type Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-switcher/)
that gives you simple way to change a post type in WordPress.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for a code solution:

```
$post_id             = 123; // Set this to the ID of the post you want to update.
$post_obj            = get_post( $post_id );
$post_obj->post_type = 'custom-post-type'; // Set this to the slug of your custom post type.
wp_update_post( $post_obj );
```

Comment: What about the extra data that comes with the post? For example the metadata and taxonomies?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "[Convert Post Type](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/)" to convert from your categories to custom post types that you have already defined.

This plugin will convert all your selected categories to a custom post type that you can choose.

Answer (score 0):

This query will convert all posts to a different post type. You need to make sure that both the previous and new post types share the same categories and taxonomies when you register it with `register_post_type`.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type` = 'blog' WHERE `post_type` = 'post';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-transfer/) plugin, it simply does the job.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/254499)