# WP_Query: Posts within category OR custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I don't like to bother you guys, but this is already driving me nuts.

I have a legacy post model within a specific category called 'listas-2' that used shortcodes to show some fancy things. Now I have created a custom post type named 'lista' that does the same thing but way better, using post_metas.

The issue now is that I have to make an archive of both at the same time with pagination, which contains the legacy and new posts. I can't manage to show both at the same time, already tried to add a tax_query but I can't because the custom post type doesn't use it, only the common post. I also tried to merge the queries but I got lots of pagination issues.

The goal: A WP_Query that requests posts within the category 'listas-2' and custom posts named 'lista', that does not have categories.

What can I do? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English, Vinicius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think that you have over complicated things here. Here is how I would treat the matter

- First of all, create a custom post type (which you have already done)
- Assign a custom taxonomy to it
- Convert all the posts from the `listas-2` category to your created custom post type. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12087/31545) on how to
- Re-assign your custom taxonomy to these converted posts

Comment: Hi Pieter! That's what I thought at the first place, but then I realized that I can't do this because these older type of posts have permalinks linked to facebook likes & comments, and doing this migration would make them all disappear.

Comment: Then why don't you assign the default categories to your custom post type and then assign the custom post type posts to your desired category. This is the only way that I can see to keep your custom query down to one, otherwise you'll need to run two custom queries, and merge them, and as you said, it becomes a mess if you add pagination to the equation

Comment: I've finally solved this by using a major part of your answer. I've added for the *listas-2* category a post_meta called *_is_lh_lista* and did that for the custom post type too. Now I can query by meta key and value and works like a charm. Thanks for giving the idea!