# How can I convert custom posts types into regular posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a Wordpress site that I just updated to 3.1. I use custom post types now, but how can I assign or convert a created custom post type to a regular post type?

For example, all of my articles (news, poems, ideas to change the world) are a custom post type. Now I have created the category in posts named `News`, and I want to transfer my old custom post types to these new posts, so that instead of a new post type it uses the default post type, just a category instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert Posts into Custom type posts?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/how-can-i-convert-posts-into-custom-type-posts)

Comment: @Milo No no i don't need to convert to custom , i need to convert from custom to posts ??

Comment: it's the same answer, just reversed.

Comment: no no i try its not same answer, are you try !!!

Comment: what did you try exactly? all post types are in the same table, switching them just changes the name stored in `post_type` column, so the process is exactly the same regardless of what you're converting to/from.

Comment: i change the post_type column, but how can put it in category ??

Comment: Then [edit] your question, show what happened after you used the answer @Milo linked to and where you are stuck.